# Android Studio IDE auto-complete: turn off newline / carriage return

Tags: android-studio, dart

When performing auto-complete on a line of code in Android Studio, in a Dart file, a carriage return / newline is added after completing the current line.

Is there a way to **turn off / prevent the newline** when auto-completing?

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

`Ctrl + Shift + Enter` will complete the current expression, add a semicolon and move to the next line without an extra newline.

---

Previous:

Use the hotkey/keymap combination for Show Context Actions (on Windows `alt` + `Enter` by default) will show a Context Menu on the line with a suggestion for completing/ending the current line.

If the suggested Context Action is "`insert ;`" it will auto-complete the line without a carriage return / new line.